# Tensors furnish representations of the group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensors

I'm bad at english, so what exactly does it mean in simple english that **Tensors furnish representations of the group**?

Answer (score 1):

It means that if we have representations $V$ and $W$ of G, then $V \otimes W$ is a representation of G as well.

Comment: So e.g. in SU(5) some reps are $\phi^i$ and $\phi^{ij}$ asymmetric in $ij$. So according to you what else is a rep of SU(5), given the above two?

Comment: Well, $\phi^i \otimes \phi^{ij} $ would be the tensorproduct of these representations and would be a representation in itself. Often, this tensor is abstract and it could be an exercise in itself to figure out what it consists of, but it is an actual representation of the group.

Comment: OK I was thinking along those line. BTW, You mean $\phi^i \otimes \phi^{jk}:=\phi^{ijk}$?.

Comment: Well, that would depend on your definiton of $\phi^{ijk} I guess